# Why is K-Means a special case of Mean-Shift algorithm?

Tags: clustering, k-means, density-estimation

I have read the paper of Yizong Cheng about Mean Shift, [Mean shift, mode seeking, and clustering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/400568) , but I didn't understand exactly, how did he concluded that KMeans is a Special case of Mean Shift Algorithm !
Can you please explain this part to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is the special case of *not* the original mean-shift but the modified version of it, defined in Definition 2 of the paper. In k-means, cluster centers are found using the algorithm defined in Example 2 in the paper, i.e. every point is assigned to the nearest cluster center and the new cluster means are calculated. There, the author defines a weight $v_{t,s}$ which represents the weight of point $s$ (a point in the dataset) to the point $t$ (a cluster center). This is a binary mapping in k-means. The modified mean-shift in the paper uses the following formula as weighting: $$w_{t,s}=\frac{K^\beta(s-t)}{\sum_t K^\beta(s-t)}$$
If $K$ is a strictly decreasing kernel, taking $\beta$ to infinity means promoting the largest component in the sum in the denominator, which will make $w_{t,s}=1$ only when the numerator is that $t$, i.e. when $||s-t||_2$ is minimum, which also means the closest cluster; else $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Answer.

Comment: You're welcome!